# Show that $\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} = \log 2 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} = \log 2 $$

I'm not sure how I can prove that.

I have tried changing the term to $-\cos(n\pi)/n$, but that doesn't help me much.  Any hint?  Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

Recall the Taylor series for log
\begin{align*}
\log x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(x-1)^n.
\end{align*}
Plugging in $x=2$ solves your problem.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know it, is there a way to deduct it, if I don't know the log Taylor series?

Comment: The only way induction could be reasonably applied is to compute the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^{n-1}/n$. However according to Mathematica this has no closed form in terms of standard functions.

Comment: It's not so much "plugging in" $x=2$. The series has a convergence radius of 1, so you have to take a limit. Abel's theorem helps here, using continuity of log.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,  \begin{align*}
\\f(t) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}.t^n}{n}.
\end{align*}

Now differentiate it with respect to t.
We get 
 \begin{align*}
\\\frac{d}{dt}f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^{n-1}.t^{n-1}}= \frac{1}{1+t}.
\end{align*}

Integrating it back with respect to t and putting t=1 gives the LHS of the given equation and the proof of the equation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that answers your question http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/abelthm.pdf

It uses the power series for $\log(1+x)$ and Abel's theorem. If you are unfamiliar with this series, it comes from integrating the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nx^n=\frac{1}{1+x}.$$